# For chrome.idle.queryState, what does thresholdSeconds argument mean?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium

Regarding: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/idle.html

Is `thresholdSeconds`:

1) insisting that the callback is only called if the system has been inactive for a certain amount of time (say 15 seconds). If so, this can't possibly mean anything sensible for the states "active", and "locked"? Can it? Would these get called?

2) A polling interval which doubles as a threshold interval? So this would go off every 15 seconds, and say that in the last 15 seconds the state was so and so.

3) Some behaviour I'm not familiar with?

At any rate, I think the documentation is poor here and should be fixed.
Testing these kind of things is laborious and sometimes gives you misleading results based on expectations, so I'd prefer an answer of some authority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think my confusion was with the asynchronous nature of the method.
It comes back immediately, and isn't itself a poller.